# How to convert different values of Farenheit to Celcius in a loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to make a for loop in Java that will convert Farenheit to Celcius starting from 30 going to 100 and

Here's what I have:

```
public static void farenheitToCelcius() {

    double farenheit = 0;

    for(double i = 30; i < 100; i += 10) {
        double celcius = ((farenheit - 32) *5) / 9;
        System.out.println(celcius);
    }
}
```

I keep getting `-17.777` printed 7 times. Would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Try using `i` in the formula somehow. Also Celsius. Not Celcius.

Comment: FWIW, `i` is a poor choice of name for a real-valued variable.  Conventionally, `i` is an integer, and most readers will at first read it that way, despite the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

In the farenheit to celsius conversion, you use `farenheit` variable (which remains constant at `0`) instead of `i`.

This would be a correct implementation (assuming the conversion equation is correct):

```java
public static void farenheitToCelcius(){
    //double farenheit = 0;
    for(double i = 30; i < 100; i += 10){
        double celcius = ((i - 32) *5) / 9;
        System.out.println(celcius);
    }
}
```

If you want to include ten, make sure the condition is `i <= 100` and make `i` an `int` to prevent round-off error.

Comment: This could be improved by choosing a different name for `i`, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69147851/trying-to-make-a-for-loop-in-java-that-will-convert-farenheit-to-celcius-startin#comment122214157_69147851).

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the incremented value, it is always using `double farenheit = 0` hence the loop is constantly outputting 17,77 as it is receiving 0 as its parameter

```
public static void farenheitToCelcius(){

double farenheit = 0;

for(double i = 30; i < 100; i += 10){
    farenheit = i; // the value needs to be set here otherwise it is always calculating 0
    double celcius = (farenheit - 32) * 5/9;
    System.out.println(celcius);
}
}
```

Comment: Thought OP would get a better idea of the problem if he saw where the value was stuck at 0

Comment: Fair enough. Good Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other two Answers are good, but could use improved naming and formatting.

Notice how we made `double` literals by appending `d` to each number.

And notice how we took the advice of [the Comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632363/user16632363) to use a descriptive name (`fahrenheit`) rather than merely `i`. This makes our code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code). In this case, using `i` is both non-descriptive *and* misleading as the type here is not an integer.

```java
public class Converters
{
    public static double fahrenheitToCelsius ( final double fahrenheit )
    {
        double celsius = ( fahrenheit - 32d ) * ( 5d / 9d );
        return celsius;
    }
}
```

And, our loop through some Fahrenheit values.

```java
double start = 30d, end = 100d;
for ( double fahrenheit = start ; fahrenheit <= end ; fahrenheit += 10 )
{
    double celsius = Converters.fahrenheitToCelsius( fahrenheit );
    System.out.println( "fahrenheit " + fahrenheit + " ⟹ celsius " + celsius );
}
```

When run.

```
fahrenheit 30.0 ⟹ celsius -1.1111111111111112
fahrenheit 40.0 ⟹ celsius 4.444444444444445
fahrenheit 50.0 ⟹ celsius 10.0
fahrenheit 60.0 ⟹ celsius 15.555555555555557
fahrenheit 70.0 ⟹ celsius 21.11111111111111
fahrenheit 80.0 ⟹ celsius 26.666666666666668
fahrenheit 90.0 ⟹ celsius 32.22222222222222
fahrenheit 100.0 ⟹ celsius 37.77777777777778
```

Bonus: You could use streams to write a one-liner. Not that this is an improvement in this case, but FYI.

We use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to generate a sequence of integer numbers while incrementing by ten, convert those to `double` values, and convert to celsius, while sending each result to the console.

```
IntStream.iterate( 30 , fahrenheit -> fahrenheit + 10 ).limit( ( ( 100 - 30 ) / 10 ) + 1 ).asDoubleStream().map( Converters :: fahrenheitToCelsius ).forEach( System.out :: println );
```

Or, reformatted:

```java
IntStream
        .iterate( 30 , fahrenheit -> fahrenheit + 10 )
        .limit( ( ( 100 - 30 ) / 10 ) + 1 )
        .asDoubleStream()
        .map( Converters :: fahrenheitToCelsius )
        .forEach( System.out :: println );
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/hE9ZkD).

Or write the conversion into that one-liner, rather than call another method.

```java
IntStream
        .iterate( 30 , fahrenheit -> fahrenheit + 10 )
        .limit( ( ( 100 - 30 ) / 10 ) + 1 )
        .asDoubleStream()
        .map( fahrenheit -> ( fahrenheit - 32d ) * ( 5d / 9d ) )
        .forEach( System.out :: println );
```

Comment: So appending d to a variable is essentially the same as appending a float like 1f? I actually didn't know that

Comment: @Armin Yes. Append `d` or `D` for `double` literals. Uppercase could be misread as a zero, so I recommend lowercase.